# Sync a Network Drive to a MS OneDrive account using Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, onedrive, network-drive

I'm curious is there is anyway to sync a network drive to a MS OneDrive account.  All computers connected to the network drive use Windows 7 (64).  What we are wanting to do is have an automatic cloud "backup" of all our music and photos that we currently store on the network drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subst` to map it on a disk volume.

Assuming your OneDrive folder is under *`C:\Users\<USERNAME>\OneDrive`* you can map it on drive **`N:\`** by writing on command prompt:

```
subst N: C:\Users\<USERNAME>\OneDrive
```

Change `<USERNAME>` with your windows account's username

You can find the exact path to your OneDrive by **right clicking on OneDrive** -> select **properties**